# React Redux - Uncaught error ... is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

New to this..

I see a number of questions offering solutions to the problem above but this is not with a reducer but a simple function.

The odd thing is, I have pretty much exactly the same structure in another file calling and retrieving, in this case, a token and it works. I pretty much followed the same pattern in the above case but when I run the program in this situation it tells me that what I am calling is not a function.

OK so here is where I call the function including the import statement for the file for that function.

```
import { saveSelectData, confirmSelectDataExistance } from '../selectData/localStorageDropDowns'
....
    //selectData download if nothing is local storage.
    const testSelectDataExistance = confirmSelectDataExistance()
    if (testSelectDataExistance) {
....
```

..and here is the code block that `confirmSelectDataExistance` above is refering to:

```
export const confirmSelectDataExistance = () => {
  const companyStateShortNameJson = localStorage.getItem(COMPANYSTATESHORTNAME)
  const statesJson = localStorage.getItem(STATES)
  const suburbLocationsJson = localStorage.getItem(LOCATIONS)
  if (companyStateShortNameJson || statesJson || suburbLocationsJson) {
    console.log('something exists in localstorage')
    return true
  }
    console.log('nothing in localstorage')
  return null
}
```

Its pretty simple and really tests to see if anything is in `localStorage`.

Now as I said I am brand new at this. I may not have added enough info. Let me know. As I said I had pretty much the same pattern for retrieving a token and its working perfectly. This however, throws this error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _localStorageDropDowns.confirmSelectDataExistance) is not a function
at reducer.js:30
at index.js:11
at Object.requestLoginToken (LoginContainer.jsx:33)
at LoginContainer._this.submit (LoginContainer.jsx:19)
at doSubmit (handleSubmit.js:39)
at handleSubmit (handleSubmit.js:101)
at Form.submit (reduxForm.js:566)
at Object.ReactErrorUtils.invokeGuardedCallback (ReactErrorUtils.js:70)
at executeDispatch (EventPluginUtils.js:85)
at Object.executeDispatchesInOrder (EventPluginUtils.js:108)
```

Given that I have the same pattern working there must be something I have missed or a simple syntax error.

EDIT

Here is the full file for "localStorageDropDowns"

```
const LOCATIONS = 'suburbLocations'
const STATES = 'states'
const COMPANYSTATESHORTNAME = 'comapanyStateShortName'


export const saveSelectData = (data) => {
  console.log('select Data', data)
  const suburbLocationsJson = JSON.stringify(data.suburbPostcodeDropDownList)
  const statesJson = JSON.stringify(data.stateDropDownList)
  const companyStateShortNameJson = JSON.stringify(data.companyStateShortName)
  localStorage.setItem(LOCATIONS, suburbLocationsJson)
  localStorage.setItem(STATES, statesJson)
  localStorage.setItem(COMPANYSTATESHORTNAME, companyStateShortNameJson)
}

export const confirmSelectDataExistance = () => {
  const companyStateShortNameJson = localStorage.getItem(COMPANYSTATESHORTNAME)
  const statesJson = localStorage.getItem(STATES)
  const suburbLocationsJson = localStorage.getItem(LOCATIONS)
  if (companyStateShortNameJson || statesJson || suburbLocationsJson) {
    console.log('something exists in localstorage')
    return true
  }
    console.log('nothing in localstorage')
  return null
}
```

Just two functions one to save and one to detect if `localStorage` has data.

Comment: Heres something that will help us debug the issue - try `import * as localStorageWrapper from "../selectData/localStorageDropDowns";` followed by `console.log(localStorageWrapper)` to make sure we are getting the right object, paste the output in a comment below. I would also just double check your file spellings as a sanity check. it looks like it finds the file but mot the function, so we can change it to `import * as foo` for better introspection as a means of debugging

Comment: This seems like an issue with your build tool, are you using babel with webpack or any other set of tools?